# FreeMarker get variable value by concatenating another variable value

Tags: java, freemarker, templating

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TemplateException{
        Configuration freemarkerConfig = new Configuration();
        freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(Main.class, "");
        Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("template.ftl");

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
           data.put("map_"+i, "value"+i);
        }
        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        template.process(data, out);
        System.out.println(out.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is my FTL code to access  the variable:

```
<#assign containerIndex=1>
${map_containerIndex} 
This gives error
I want to evaluate ${map_1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read variables with such runtime generated names like `.vars['map_' + i]`. It's the same trick than tom has used in his answer, but applied for reading a top-level variable.

Comment: lets say my return type is Object  `.vars['map_' + i].name` will this work using this method

Comment: I don't understand your question, but anyway `.vars[...]` is just an expression that gives you a value of any type. There's nothing special with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a variable (which I don't think is possible that way) I'd suggest providing an array to the template.

Like so

```
String[] stringArray = new String[11];
for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
    stringArray[i] = "value"+i;
}
data.put("map", stringArray);
```

Access in Freemarker should look like

```
<#assign containerIndex=1>
${map[containerIndex]}
```

or something like that, can't try it out atm

Also note, that by starting the for-loop with 1 (as in your example) the first array-slot won't be used.

I'd suggest

```
String[] stringArray = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stringArray[i] = "value"+i;
}
```