# Trying to generate a string that becomes a variable name in Freemarker or a "derived variable name"

Tags: freemarker, assign

I'm using a data-directive or list to pull in several values, of which, I don't know how many there will be, and I want to try and list through them, and create several variables in the list if you will.

```
<#list 1..10 as x>
<#-- the next line doesn't work, but what i'm trying to fix -->
<#assign .vars['VAR'+x?string] = rand(100) />
</#list>
```

But I can list them back out that way.

```
<#list 1..10 as x>
    ${.vars['VAR'+x?string]}
</#list>
```

The documentation for assign, says:

> name: name of the variable. It is not expression. However, it can be
> written as a string literal, which is useful if the variable name
> contains reserved characters, for example <#assign "foo-bar" = 1>.
> Note that this string literal does not expand interpolations (as
> "${foo}").

Is there no way around this? Am I trying to do the impossible? Is there some way I can insert a derived name into the .vars... Hash is it?

A little more research that was close, but didn't get me there:

- This prevoius question gives how to READ the derived variable, but I need to WRITE/CREATE the derived variable.
  [FreeMarker get variable value by concatenating another variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450736/freemarker-get-variable-value-by-concatenating-another-variable-value/33455945#33455945)
- This prevoius question shows that I can use a string to assign a variable and re-iterates what we saw in the first link.
  [Variable name in Freemarker Template Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089266/variable-name-in-freemarker-template-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FreeMarker can't assign to elements of collections (but you can `?map(it -> ...)` a collection to another), the only way is via `?interpret`:

```
<#list 1..10 as x>
<#-- the next line doesn't work, but what i'm trying to fix -->
<@'<#assign VAR${x?c} = rand(100)>'?interpret />
</#list>
```

I wonder why do you need to assign to a dynamically named variables though, since reading dynamically named variables is also a pain, even if a lesser one.

Comment: Use case is assign unknown number of coupons. Ideally we want to count, as we need to assign two (online and instore) each time.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I believe the correct way to phrase my solution was a sequence of hashes:

```
<#list 1..z_Coupon_Pet.NUM_COUPONS as x>
    <#assign INSTORE_COUPON=call_coupon_from_table1() />
    <#assign ONLINE_COUPON=call_coupon_from_table2() />
    <#assign coupon_string_row= '{
    "COUPON_NUM" : ${x},
    "INSTORE" : "${INSTORE_COUPON?js_string}",
    "ONLINE" : "${ONLINE_COUPON?js_string}"
}' />
<#if x==1>
   <#assign coupon_hash_string = coupon_string_row />
<#else>
   <#assign coupon_hash_string = coupon_hash_string + ',' + coupon_string_row />
</#if>
</#list>
</#if>
<#if coupon_hash_string?has_content>
   <#assign coupon_hash=parsejson('[' + coupon_hash_string + ']') />
</#if>
```

We specifically avoid `<#assign my_hash = my_hash + element />` because of [this note](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_hashop_cat) in the documentation:

> Note that hash concatenation is not to be used for many repeated concatenations, like for adding items to a hash inside a loop. While adding together hashes is fast and is constant time (independent of the size of the hashes added), the resulting hash is a bit slower to read than the hashes added together. Thus after tens... of additions the result can be impractically slow to read.